# Can i add a Tooltip/Popup to a HeatMapWithTime in folium?

Tags: python, heatmap, folium

I'm creating a heatmapwithtime in folium, but i need to show a tooltip/popup when passing the mouse through the map. Someone knows if i can do it?

```
  HeatMapWithTime(data, scale_radius=True, radius=25, auto_play=True, max_opacity=0.7, index= date_index, position='bottomleft', 
    name='Heatmap - Avanço do risco ao decorrer tempo',
    gradient={.25: '#1766e6', .50: '#eb6613', .75: '#f71d11', 1: '#8b0000'}).add_to(mapa)
```

The Map i Have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add Leaflet style location *Marker*, which are added to the same map which is used within *HeatMapWithTime*, with a *popup* and *tooltip* such as

```
folium.Marker(location=[-23.533773,-46.625290],
              popup='<strong>City Center</strong>',
              tooltip='Central Part',
              icon=folium.Icon(color='green', icon='cloud')).add_to(mapa)

folium.Marker(location=[-23.433773,-46.725290],
              popup='<strong>Caieiras</strong>',
              tooltip='Caieiras',
              icon=folium.Icon(color='red', icon='info-sign')).add_to(mapa)
```